# Update a field value when another field value change

Tags: angular, typescript

So, let's say I have two fields in my class for simplicity:

```js
export class SomeClass {
    selectedObjects: MyClass[];
    fieldToUpdateWhenArrayAboveChange:string;
}
```

Based on the example above, I would like to populate second field with comma separated values of first field (the array)

'selectedObjects' first field is hookup with UI via 'ngModel'

Is there a way to run custom code when a field changes in Angular 2. In C# classes that can be easily done with setters.

Comment: In your example you define both in the same class? So why don't you just update the string at the moment you change your array? And naming the array myClass is pretty confusing don't you think? ;)

Comment: The names were replaced for example purpose, in order to make it more readable. I dont update the array myself, if I would, there would be no problem. The array is being updated via binding by Angular 2 ('ngModel')

Comment: Ah ok. So why build the string? You can just flatten the array at any time?

Comment: I need to find a way to trigger a custom function that will fire when array changes. Hmm, I think I could bind to an UI event with help of Angular 2, and then parse the array any way I want. This should work. I will try that. I still would prefer to achieve that with Typescript, just like it can be done easily with C# and setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I could not figure it out with typescript itself, but was able to achieve the desired effect with Angular 2 event binding. I have introduced 'ngModelChange' on the field that was bound to the mentioned array (multiselect input field). When array changes, it triggers the method below, where I parse the array any way I want and populate other typescript fields

(ngModelChange)='updateTitleAndDescription()'